# Android phone restarts on updating notification

Tags: android, xamarin

Im making an app on Xamarin for android, and the app works perfectly on my Samsung phone with Android 6.

I have a part where I download some PDFs through the app, and in the process, notification keeps showing the percent of progress done.

But so far, 2 android phones with Android 5.1 on them keep restarting in that piece of code. if I remove the notification update code, the download will go through and nothing weird happens, but when the notification is updating, the phone restarts after 1-2 percent (or better say, after 1-2 times the notification gets updated).

Also the same piece of code makes my own phone a little slow while updating the notification, so I know it's not entirely perfect.

Can anyone suggest a work around? thanks.

Here is the code:

```
private void downloadprogress(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.ProgressPercentage < 100)
            {
                mBuilder.SetProgress(100, e.ProgressPercentage, false);
                mBuilder.SetContentText("Downloading - " + e.ProgressPercentage + "%");
                mNotifyManager.Notify(Convert.ToInt32(bookid), mBuilder.Build());
            }
            else
            {
                mBuilder.SetProgress(100, e.ProgressPercentage, false);
                mBuilder.SetContentText("Preparing the file");
                mNotifyManager.Notify(Convert.ToInt32(bookid), mBuilder.Build());
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

this is the notification flags:

```
Notification.Builder mBuilder;
NotificationManager mNotifyManager; 
mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
        mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(Application.Context);
        if (!downloadingdemo)
            mBuilder.SetContentTitle(title);
        else
            mBuilder.SetContentTitle(title + "(demo)");
        mBuilder.SetContentText("Downloading - " + "0%");
        mBuilder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.CCicon);
        mBuilder.SetAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.SetOngoing(true);
        mBuilder.SetProgress(100, 0, false);
        mNotifyManager.Notify(Convert.ToInt32(bookid), mBuilder.Build());
```

Comment: Why don't you use the catch block to write a log to file or even the adb ?

Comment: @CarlosFerreira well the phone just restarts while doing it, I don't think any error happens there since it works on my phone without restart (even though it's not smooth). Maybe some RAM issue happens or something? I'm hoping people with more experience can help with it.

Comment: In what phones does it restart ? Brand, Model and Android version

Comment: @CarlosFerreira Samsung S4 with Andorid 5.0.1  and Samsung Prime with android 5.1

Comment: empty catch block? seems like you're getting what you're asking for.

Comment: Can you tell which flags are you using on the notification intent ?

Comment: @CarlosFerreira I added everything related to the notification. tnx for your attention

Comment: @Shark It's empty because an error is not much of a big deal here, at worst it's not gonna update the notification for 1-2%. besides, since this is happening fast, If I remove the Try Catch, the app will crash while updating the notification,so that's why it's an empty catch phrase, just to ignore any error in that part, but restarting it? that's unexpected.

Comment: Just a hunch...try changing the text to an english message.
There were some bugs on lollipop regarding rtl languages.

Comment: @CarlosFerreira huh, didn't thought that could cause any problems. I'll check it out in a few minutes and let u know, thanks

Comment: Also share your build tools version from gradle if possible. Thanks

Comment: @CarlosFerreira I have Android SDK build tools version from 17 to 23.0.3
and I tried changing texts to english, didn't help.

Comment: @Shark I added an Exception to my catch block to know if any error happens, but guess what? no error. just the phone restarts.

Comment: i'm not saying it's restarting due to an empty `catch { }` block. I'm saying that whatever gets caught, you won't know about it. at least put a log there, and print the stacktrace so you have a clue that something is happening.

As far as restarts go, wait until you get a Huawei / HTC / Xiaomi phone in your / user's hands, thats when the fun starts.

Comment: `adb logcat *:s AndroidRuntime:v System.err:v DEBUG:v libc:v` do they come up with a native stacktrace if you're using some native libraries?

Comment: Maybe xamarin runtime crashing the phone ?

Comment: @CarlosFerreira Only on some phones? and both with android 5? and only when notification is getting updated? (as I said, wont crash without those update lines). and if that's the case, what could I do to fix it?

Comment: @shark I'm sorry, I'm not a professional about android, I know C# and windows, and thanks to xamarin I've been able to make an android app, but I have this issue for now. So, I'm kinda not sure what those codes you wrote (adb logcat *:s AndroidRuntime:v System.err:v DEBUG:v libc:v) means and what I should do with them.

Comment: @FarhadKalatiani the following:

Go to Project options (double click on Android project)
Go to Android build under build section
Go to Advanced tab and only use armeabi-v7a
Test it again on the crashing phone

Comment: @CarlosFerreira Well it worked for the first file for some reason and I was so happy that it is fixed, but then I tried downloading another file and the restarting kept happening again.

Comment: Try using just armeabi-v7a and disable the others.
Without any more details, i'm just fishing.

Comment: @CarlosFerreira well as I said I tried and didn't work. anyway, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so as I mentioned in one of my comments, RunOnUIThread did the job. And to prevent slowness in the app, I limited the update amount. So this is the final code which has worked fine so far on every phone and tablet I have tested on:

```
try
        {
            if (e.ProgressPercentage % 30 == 0 || e.ProgressPercentage == 100)
            {
                if (e.ProgressPercentage < 100)
                {
                    RunOnUiThread(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        mBuilder.SetProgress(100, e.ProgressPercentage, false);
                        mBuilder.SetContentText("Downloading - " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
                        mNotifyManager.Notify(notid, mBuilder.Build());
                    }));
                }
                else
                {
                    RunOnUiThread(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        mBuilder.SetProgress(100, e.ProgressPercentage, false);
                        mBuilder.SetContentText("Preparing the file");
                        mNotifyManager.Notify(notid, mBuilder.Build());
                    }));
                }
            }
        }
        catch {};
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would have posted a comment, but they seem to be quite filled up.

How many times are you updating the notification per second? (Try logging this) Do you need to throttle it to only change if it changes a whole percentage point?

I suspect you are slamming the `NotificationManager` with too many calls, and it might not work on older devices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.The update per second really depends on the internet speed of the user,It's being updated 100 times for every percent.Anyways, I wrapped the updating in a RunOnUiThread since it's in another thread actually, doesn't make much sense since it's working perfectly on my own phone without that, but surprisingly, it seems to have worked and fixed the issue. And to prevent slowness on the app, I have limited the update to 4 times, on 30/60/90/100%.I haven' yet updated my topic here because I yet haven't checked it fully on the other crashing phone. I'll update it if that works.